# Three20 Show Menu For Cell Without Sliding Animation

Tags: iphone, three20

```
[self showMenu:view forCell:cell animated:NO];
```

How do you override this method in Three20 so that it won't do a sliding animation and it won't remove the contents of your TableViewCell?
I just want to show menu like what Facebook App does when showing the Comment and Like Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if ever, there's still someone out there having this problem, what I did was to override both of these methods, and somehow, it's working fine..

```
- (void)showMenu:(UIView *)view forCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self hideMenu:NO];
    _menuView = [view retain];
    _menuCell = [cell retain];
    [_menuCell.contentView addSubview:_menuView];
}

- (void)hideMenu:(BOOL)animated {
    if (_menuView) {
        [_menuView removeFromSuperview];
        TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_menuView);
        TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_menuCell);
    }
}
```